# Why is jQuery toggleClass not removing a class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have made a Skills accordion but I now want to create a button to toggle all the skill sections. When I am doing this, the jQuery isn't removing/adding the class when it needs to on the .accordion-trigger-all.
I originally use .click() but then I changed to .on("click", function) but still no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-single:not(.open) + .skill-container").hide()

  $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-single").click(function() {

    $(this).next(".skill-container").slideToggle()

    $(this).toggleClass("open")

    allOpen()

  })

  function allOpen() {
    if ($(".skill-container").is(":hidden")) {

      $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all h3").html("Open All")
      $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all").removeClass("open")

    } else {

      $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all h3").html("Close All")
      $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all").addClass("open")

    }
  }

  allOpen()
  //
  $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all:not(.open)").on('click', function() {

    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-single:not(.open) + .skill-container").slideDown()
    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-single:not(.open)").toggleClass("open")

    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all.open h3").html("Close All")
    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all").addClass("open")

    allOpen()

  })

  $(".accordion .accordion-trigger-all.open").on("click", function() {

    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger-single.open + .skill-container").slideUp()
    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger-single.open").toggleClass("open")

    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all h3").html("Open All")
    $(".accordion .accordion-trigger.accordion-trigger-all").removeClass("open")

  })

})
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #9CA3AF;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9CA3AF;
  background-color: #F9FAFB;
}

.accordion .accordion-trigger:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.accordion .accordion-trigger.open {
  border-bottom: #059669 3px solid;
  background-color: #ECFDF5;
}

.accordion .accordion-trigger h3 {
  padding: 6px;
  font-weight: initial;
  margin: 0;
  color: #9CA3AF;
}

.accordion .accordion-trigger.open h3 {
  color: #059669;
}

.accordion .skill-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .skill {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion .skill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #312E81;
  border-radius: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: animateLeft 1s ease-out;
  width: var(--l);
}

.accordion .skill:nth-child(even)::before {
  background-color: #374151;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  from {
    left: -100%
  }
  to {
    left: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">

  <div class="accordion-trigger accordion-trigger-all">
    <h3>Close All</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-trigger accordion-trigger-single open">
    <h3>Web Essentials</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-container">

    <span class="skill" style="--l:100%;">HTML</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:70%">CSS</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:60%">Responsive</span>

  </div>

  <div class="accordion-trigger accordion-trigger-single open">
    <h3>JavaScript Skills</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-container">

    <span class="skill" style="--l:90%">Vanilla JavaScript</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:80%">jQuery</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:30%">Google Maps</span>

  </div>


  <div class="accordion-trigger accordion-trigger-single open">
    <h3>Server-Side</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-container">

    <span class="skill" style="--l:50%">PHP</span>
    <span class="skill" style="--l:30%">MySQL</span>

  </div>

  <div class="accordion-trigger accordion-trigger-single open">
    <h3>Tools of the Trade</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-container">

    <span class="skill" style="--l:100%">PHPStorm</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:90%">MAMP</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:90%">OSX</span>

    <span class="skill" style="--l:60%">Git Version Control</span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: :not(.open)").toggleClass("open") suggests to me it can only ever ADD the class

Comment: You have `.toggleClass("open")` 3 places... And they all act on `.accordion-trigger-single`... Not on `.accordion-trigger-all`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would I go about this @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Add a `$(this).toggleClass("open")` in both `.on("click"` handlers...

Comment: It only works one way, so even if I removed the class instead of adding it, the opposite will not work. I want it to be so that the toggle can open all AND close all however right now it will just do one of those

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette sorry this does not work either, I have just tried it

Comment: I think this issue may have something to do with the $(document).ready() but I have tried different things but I can't figure out what

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer for this:
When jQuery loads, it assigns an event handler to the `$(".accordion .accordion-trigger-all.open").on('click', function()` so at the beginning it only finds whichever is open. However when it searches again it doesn't find the element with the class removed.

Simple solution: `$(".accordion").on('click','.accordion-trigger-all.open', function()`

which will add the event handler to the whole element, instead of the only the element with the class `.open`

The same should be done for the opposite: `$(".accordion").on('click','.accordion-trigger-all:not(.open)', function()`